# Compile with /MDD when MSVC is overriding '/MDd' with '/MD'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, v8, gyp

I'm trying to use V8 in my project. So I built it using `python build\gyp_v8 -Dtarget_arch=ia32 -Dcomponent=shared_library`. I built it under Debug and Release and included the one in Debug. But I get for example:

```
icuuc.lib(ucnv2022.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicRelease' does not match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Whitedrop.obj [C:\OgreSDK\Projects\whi tedrop\build_win32\Whitedrop.vcxproj]
```

**EDIT:** MSVC throws several warning like this:

```
Warning 81  warning D9025: overriding '/MDd' with '/MD' C:\ChromeV8\v8\tools\gyp\cl v8_base
```

Comment: You really should not repost your exact same question again, your previous one is one vote away from being reopened.

Comment: I have the exact opposite prb, by default V8 compiled as MT with VS2013 installed, and to  make it MD have to run:
python build\gyp_v8 -Dtarget_arch=ia32 -Dcomponent=shared_library

Comment: @FernandoGonzalezSanchez sorry i don't understand. Is it a solution?

Comment: Yes, with "-Dcomponent=shared_library" the generated solution will generate DLLs and .lib stubs (and thus link against MD).

Comment: Now I get 'MD_DynamicRelease' mismatch with 'MD_DynamicDebug', but the .lib linked is in Debug :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got exactly the same problem as you some time ago, and here is how I resolved it:

Open VS 2013, and in each project, open its properties, C++ > Command Line and clear the Additional Options area. Do this for every project whenever you can recompile and voilà!